# Exchange MSExchangeIS Mailbox Store Error

Tags: exchange, exchange-2003

Boss asked me to check to see if I could figure out why he's had to restart the services on the Exchange server three mornings in a row now.

While going through the system logs I ran across an error from the MSExchangeIs Mailbox Store, category General, Event 9690.

The message said (edited to make generalized):

---

Exchange store 'First Storage Group\Mailbox Store (Servername)': The logical size of this database (the logical size equals the physical size of the .edb file and the .stm file minus the logical free space in each) is 22GB. This database size has exceeded the size limit of 22 GB.

This database will be dismounted immediately.

---

Hmm...happened at five in the morning, and I'm thinking this is a pretty good hint that this leads to the culprit. Thing is I'm not an Exchange expert, so I'm still googling around to figure out how to fix the problem. Any better guidance out there? Or am I barking up the wrong binary tree?

Exchange System Manager reports that the server is "version 6.5 build 7638.2, SP2", standard, which I believe is Exchange 2003. It's running on Windows Server 2003 R2 Standard, SP2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should take care of it for you:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa998066(EXCHG.65).aspx

Comment: Make sure you have SP2 for Exchange installed.

Comment: Glad to help...